# How does the std::string constructor handle char[] of fixed size?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

How does the string constructor handle `char[]` of a fixed size when the actual sequence of characters in that `char[]` could be smaller than the maximum size?

```
char foo[64];//can hold up to 64
char* bar = "0123456789"; //Much less than 64 chars, terminated with '\0'
strcpy(foo,bar); //Copy shorter into longer
std::string banz(foo);//Make a large string
```

In this example will the size of the `banz` objects string be based on the original char* length or the char[] that it is copied into?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you have to remember (or know) that `char` strings in C++ are really called ***null-terminated*** byte strings. That *null-terminated* bit is a special character (`'\0'`) that tells the end of the string.

The second thing you have to remember (or know) is that arrays naturally decays to pointers to the arrays first element. In the case of `foo` from your example, when you use `foo` the compiler really does `&foo[0]`.

Finally, if we look at e.g. [this `std::string` constructor reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) you will see that there is an overload (number 5) that accepts a `const CharT*` (with `CharT` being a `char` for normal `char` strings).

Putting it all together, with

```
std::string banz(foo);
```

you pass a pointer to the first character of `foo`, and the `std::string` constructor will treat it as a null-terminated byte string. And from finding the null-terminator it knows the length of the string. The actual size of the array is irrelevant and not used.

If you want to set the size of the `std::string` object, you need to explicitly do it by passing a length argument (variant 4 in the constructor reference):

```
std::string banz(foo, sizeof foo);
```

This will ignore the null-terminator and set the length of `banz` to the size of the array. Note that the null-terminator will still be stored in the string, so passing a pointer (as retrieved by e.g. the [`c_str`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) function) to a function which expects a null-terminated string, then the string will seem short. Also note that the data after the null-terminator will be *uninitialized* and have *indeterminate* contents. You *must* initialize that data before you use it, otherwise you will have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and in C++ even reading indeterminate data is UB).

---

As mentioned in a comment from MSalters, the UB from reading uninitialized and indeterminate data also goes for the construction of the `banz` object using an explicit size. It will typically work and not lead to any problems, but it does break the rules set out in the C++ specification.

Fixing it is easy though:

```
char foo[64] = { 0 };//can hold up to 64
```

The above will initialize *all* of the array to zero. The following `strcpy` call will not touch the data of the array beyond the terminator, and as such the remainder of the array will be initialized.

Comment: It might be worth emphasizing that "You must initialize that data _past `\0`_ before you use it," also includes using it in `std::string banz(foo, sizeof foo);``

Comment: @Caleth I know + with the last edit of the answer, I dont see anymore a chance of getting it wrong, comment deleted

Comment: I don't think reading indeterminate chars is not UB; that is not true of other types.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: in your first sentence, you have a double negative. This is UB in English.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont And in C++ access to uninitialized scalar values (and just about all types except class and array types are scalar, most importantly `char` is a scalar type) is UB.

Comment: You can use `char foo[64] = {};` too in newer standards; an important departure from C.

Comment: @some depends if the char is unsigned it turns out: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=88046609#content/view/88046609

Comment: it's relatively old now. New is  `char e[50]{};`

Comment: So as I understand this, as long as the fixed size char[] is initialized to the null terminator the string constructor will only include up to and including the first null terminator. So the size of `banz` would be 11, 10 chars plus null terminator? `banz.compare("0123456789") would return 0?

Comment: @hehe3301 With the initialization of `banz` you show in your question, yes that's correct. Except that the length of the string is `10`, as the terminator is not counted.

Answer (score 4):

The constructor called is one that takes a `const char*` as an argument. That constructor attempts to copy the character data pointed to by that pointer, *until* the first NUL terminator is reached. If there is no such NUL terminator then the behaviour of the constructor is *undefined*.

Your `foo` type is converted to a `char*` by *pointer decay*, then an implicit conversion to `const char*` occurs at the calling site.

Perhaps there could have been a templatised `std::string` constructor taking a `const char[N]` as an argument, which would have allowed the insertion of more than one NUL character (the `std::string` class after all does support that), but it was not introduced and to do so now would be a breaking change; using

```
std::string foo{std::begin(foo), std::end(foo)};
```

will also copy the entire array `foo`.

Comment: cppreference gives a constructor with char* and int to make a string out of the array instead of the c-style string

Comment: @stefaanv there is *also* a `char *, int` constructor *as well as* the `char *` constructor mentioned here. but there isn't an automatic conversion from `template <size_t N> foo(char (&str)[N])` to `foo(char *, size_t)`

Comment: @stefaanv: I'd argue that the canonical C+11 way is `std::string foo{ std::begin(array), std::end(array) };`.